# Android Studio Loading Internal Storage Data Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, persistence, loading

I have just started learning Android Studio and have been working on a basic note taking app for a while. I have added load/save methods to the main fragment. But when I first start the app it crashes. If I remove load methods and start the app then app works as I want. After I add load methods again and start the app second time then app works with no problem as well. So I assume there is a problem with my loading code as it causes the app crash when I start the first time. You can find the main fragment code which is the first screen, and also the error I receive in Android Studio below. I'd appreciate it greatly if you could help me to fix this issue.

**MainProjectList.java fragment:**

```
public class MainProjectLister extends ListFragment implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    Button addProjectButton;
    EditText addProjectEditText;
    public String projectTitle;
    Projekt newProjekt;
    ProjektSingleton projektSingleton;
    ArrayList<Projekt> projektArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<Projekt> tempProjektArrayList;

    ArrayList<String> ListOfP;

    private final String FILENAME="testfile15.txt";
    private final String FILENAME2="testfile16.txt";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListOfP = new ArrayList<String>();
        projektSingleton = ProjektSingleton.getInstance();
        projektSingleton.setProjektList(getSavedArrayList());
        ListOfP = getSavedStringList();

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_project_lister_layout, container, false);

        addProjectButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addProjectButton);
        addProjectEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.addProjectEditText);

//addProjectButton onClck method

        addProjectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

//Checking if nothing is entered in the EditText and gives Error messaga
               if(TextUtils.isEmpty(addProjectEditText.getText().toString().trim())){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please type details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                projectTitle = addProjectEditText.getText().toString();
                newProjekt = new Projekt(projectTitle);
                projektArrayList = projektSingleton.getProjectList();
                projektArrayList.add(newProjekt);

                ListOfP.add(projectTitle);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                saveArrayList(projektArrayList);
                saveStringList(ListOfP);
                addProjectEditText.setText("");

            }

        });

        getActivity().setTitle("DearBear Notes App");
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ListOfP);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){

        MainProjectLister frag = new MainProjectLister();
        ProjectListFragmentChanger fragInterface = (ProjectListFragmentChanger) getActivity();
        fragInterface.projectListChangeFragment(frag);

        projektSingleton.setProjectNumber(i);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
        projektArrayList = projektSingleton.getProjectList();
        projektArrayList.remove(i);
        ListOfP.remove(i);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        saveArrayList(projektArrayList);
        saveStringList(ListOfP);

        return true;
    }

    //Interface

    public interface ProjectListFragmentChanger{

        public void projectListChangeFragment(Fragment fragment);

    }

//Save File Method
    public void saveArrayList(ArrayList<Projekt> arrayList) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(arrayList);
            out.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

    public void saveStringList(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(FILENAME2, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(arrayList);
            out.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }


//Load Text File Method

    public ArrayList<Projekt> getSavedArrayList() {
        ArrayList<Projekt> savedArrayList = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput(FILENAME);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            savedArrayList = (ArrayList<Projekt>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

        return savedArrayList;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSavedStringList() {
        ArrayList<String> savedArrayList = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput(FILENAME2);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            savedArrayList = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        return savedArrayList;
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.lenovo.projectlist/com.example.lenovo.projectlist.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 2394 on device Nexus_5_API_24 [emulator-5554]
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.lenovo.projectlist-2/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.lenovo.projectlist, real application class is null.
I/art: Debugger is no longer active
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.lenovo.projectlist-2/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.lenovo.projectlist/files/testfile15.txt (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:485)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:186)
W/System.err:     at com.example.lenovo.projectlist.MainProjectLister.getSavedArrayList(MainProjectLister.java:189)
W/System.err:     at com.example.lenovo.projectlist.MainProjectLister.onCreate(MainProjectLister.java:53)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2335)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
W/System.err:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:857)
W/System.err:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:880)
W/System.err:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:727)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:371)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6680)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.lenovo.projectlist/files/testfile16.txt (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:485)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:186)
W/System.err:     at com.example.lenovo.projectlist.MainProjectLister.getSavedStringList(MainProjectLister.java:208)
W/System.err:     at com.example.lenovo.projectlist.MainProjectLister.onCreate(MainProjectLister.java:54)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2335)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
W/System.err:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:857)
W/System.err:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:880)
W/System.err:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:727)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:371)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6680)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.lenovo.projectlist, PID: 2394
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lenovo.projectlist/com.example.lenovo.projectlist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:344)
                      at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:493)
                      at android.app.ListFragment.setListAdapter(ListFragment.java:240)
                      at com.example.lenovo.projectlist.MainProjectLister.onActivityCreated(MainProjectLister.java:111)
                      at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2361)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1014)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:815)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
                      at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:371)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6680)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error happens because you call `openFileInput()` on a file that hasn't been created yet. But since you catch that error, `getSavedArrayList()` returns `null` and assigns that to `ListOfP` causing the NullPointerException when you try to assign null to your ArrayAdapter.

To prevent that, you should check if the file exists first, and assign your list to an empty one to prevent both errors; like so:

```
public ArrayList<Projekt> getSavedArrayList() {
    ArrayList<Projekt> savedArrayList = null;
    try {
        // get the file and check if it exists before trying to read it
        File savedFile = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
        if (savedFile.exists()) {
            // if the file containing the list exists, read it and return the list
            FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput(FILENAME);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            savedArrayList = (ArrayList<Projekt>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } else {
            // if it doesn't exist, return an empty list
            savedArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
    return savedArrayList;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! @CarlosSifuentes